# Syntax problems when parameterizing filters in jq in a bash function

Tags: bash, filter, dynamic, syntax, jq

I'm using `jq` in a `bash` script to search for items in arrays that can be found anywhere in a json file. I have already written a function that has bad practices that solves the problem. I want to know how to do it correctly before writing more scripts that use `jq`.

Here is an example of a json file, `silly-sample.json`:

```
{
  "fruits_with_a":[
    {"fruitName":"Apple","value":"..."},
    {"fruitName":"Apricot","value":"..."},
    {"fruitName":"Aratiles","value":"..."},
    {"fruitName":"Araza","value":"..."},
    {"fruitName":"Avocado","value":"..."}
  ],
  "fruits_with_b":[
    {"name":"Banana","value":"..."},
    {"name":"Blackberry","value":"..."},
    {"name":"Black sapote","value":"..."},
    {"name":"Blueberry","value":"..."},
    {"name":"Breadfruit","value":"..."}
  ],
  "fruits_with_c":[
    {"id":"Cherry","value":"..."},
    {"id":"Coconut","value":"..."},
    {"id":"Cranberry","value":"..."}
  ],
  "fruits_with_d":[
    {"sku":"Dragonfruit","value":"..."},
    {"sku":"Durian","value":"..."}
  ],
  "vegetables":{
    "with_a":[
      {"n":"artichoke","value":"..."},
      {"n":"aubergine","value":"..."},
      {"n":"asparagus","value":"..."}
    ],
    "with_b":[
      {"n":"broccoflower","value":"..."},
      {"n":"broccoli","value":"..."},
      {"n":"brussels sprouts","value":"..."}
    ],
    "with_c":[
      {"n":"cabbage","value":"..."},
      {"n":"cauliflower","value":"..."},
      {"n":"celery","value":"..."},
      {"n":"cichory","value":"..."}
    ]
  }
}
```

Most of the searches I perform are pretty simple and follow a pattern. The parameters that change are: the *array* on which I want to perform the search, the *field* I want to use for the search and the *value* I want to search for. Here are some examples of the queries I perform with `jq`:

`jq -r '.fruits_with_b[] | select(.name=="Blackberry")' "./silly-sample.json"`

`jq -r '.fruits_with_c[] | select(.id=="Coconut")' "./silly-sample.json"`

`jq -r '.vegetables.with_a[] | select(.n=="aubergine")' "./silly-sample.json"`

As mentioned, I created a `bash` function (`retrieve_from_array`) to generalize the way my script searches for an item in an array. At that time I didn't know the correct way to pass parameters to `jq` using `--arg` and what I ended up doing was concatenating the entire command into a string and then executing it using eval. So far, that solution has worked perfectly.

```
retrieve_from_array(){
  local jq_query jq_result && \
  jq_query="jq -r '.${1}[] | select(.${2}==\"${3}\")' \"./silly-sample.json\"" && \
  jq_result="$(eval "${jq_query}")" && \
  echo "${jq_result}" && \
  return 0

  return 1
}

retrieve_from_array "fruits_with_a" "fruitName" "Apricot" && echo "Executed successfully!!!"
retrieve_from_array "vegetables.with_a" "n" "asparagus" && echo "Executed successfully!!!"
```

Now I need to write more `bash` functions with `jq` to perform additional searches with more conditions. The logical thing to do would be to continue using string concatenation and add more conditions, more operators and more values as the searches need it and then execute with eval, but that does not seem to be a good practice to scale.

I have tried to rewrite the `retrieve_from_array` function by passing parameters to `jq` using `--arg` and interpolating the parameters in various ways within `jq`´s filter syntax, but have had no success.

```
retrieve_from_array_v2(){
  local jq_result && \
  jq_result="$(jq -r --arg a "${1}" --arg k "${2}" --arg v "${3}" '.$a[] | select(.$k=="$v")' "./silly-sample.json")" && \
  echo "${jq_result}" && \
  return 0

  return 1
}
```

I get a `jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '$' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:` error message.

The problem is not in replacing the *value* I want to search for (`=="Blackberry"`, `=="celery"`). Syntax errors start appearing when I try to replace the *array* (`.vegetables.with_a[]`, `.fruits_with_a[]`) and *field* (`.sku`, `.name`) with the arguments received in `jq.

How could I rewrite my `bash` function to work without using eval?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use variables defined with `--arg` options to import the parameters into the filter, and then just call `jq` without capturing its result in a variable. Its output automatically becomes the output of the function, and as the call to `jq` is the last (and only) one in the function, its exit code is also automatically re-used as exit code for the function call. To use dot notation for paths containing a series of field names, split the string by the dots, and use `getpath` with the resulting array.

```bash
retrieve_from_array2() {
  jq --arg cat "$1" --arg key "$2" --arg val "$3" \
    'getpath($cat / ".")[] | select(.[$key] == $val)' ./silly-sample.json
}
```

```json
$ retrieve_from_array2 "fruits_with_a" "fruitName" "Apricot"
{
  "fruitName": "Apricot",
  "value": "..."
}
```

```json
$ retrieve_from_array2 "vegetables.with_a" "n" "asparagus"
{
  "n": "asparagus",
  "value": "..."
}
```